# Unknown function: splice#SpliceInit at launch

Tags: vim

I installed *Splice.vim* through *Vundle* but I got these error when running `git mergetool`. Here is my `.gitconfig`:

```
[merge]¬                                                                         
    tool = splice¬                                                               
[mergetool "splice"]¬                                                            
    cmd = "vim -f $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED -c 'SpliceInit'"¬                 
    trustExitCode = true
```

Nothing original as you can see.

I satisfy the requirements. Vim 7.3, Python 2.7.1, Vim supports Python,…

Here is what `:call splice#SpliceInit()` return:

```
Error detected while processing function splice#SpliceInit:
line    3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/adrien/.vim/bundle/splice.vim/autoload/splice.py", line 19, in SpliceInit
    splice.init()
  File "/Users/adrien/.vim/bundle/splice.vim/autoload/splicelib/init.py", line 96, in init
    setlocal_buffers()
  File "/Users/adrien/.vim/bundle/splice.vim/autoload/splicelib/init.py", line 78, in setlocal_buffers
    buffers.hud.open()
  File "/Users/adrien/.vim/bundle/splice.vim/autoload/splicelib/util/bufferlib.py", line 53, in hud
    return Buffer(int(vim.eval("bufnr('__Splice_HUD__')")) - 1)
  File "/Users/adrien/.vim/bundle/splice.vim/autoload/splicelib/util/bufferlib.py", line 10, in __init__
    self._buffer = vim.buffers[i]
    IndexError: no such buffer
```

Any idea?

Comment: It would be nice if you would link to the splice.vim you're installing.  We don't know what source you're installing from.

Comment: As it's installed from [Vundle](http://github.com/gmarik/vundle), the source of [splice.vim](http://sjl.bitbucket.org/splice.vim/) is http://github.com/sjl/splice.vim.git.

Comment: Does `:call splice#SpliceInit()` do anything? Errors, maybe. Is Vim compiled with Python support (`:echo has('python')` returns `1`)? Also it can be installed from any repo, on GitHub or elsewhere.

Comment: OP updated according to your questions. I think it has to raise an error since just calling `splice#SpliceInit()` isn't good, it has to be run in a specific context (eg. merging files).

Comment: The initial error is typical of a non-installed or non-loaded plugin while the kind of error that you added in your edit is sign that it's installed and loaded. That was just a check. I think that the function is called before the plugin is loaded.

Comment: What happens if you don't use Vundle?

Comment: Im expereince similar issue, using pathogen, although i have only 2 erros instead of 3. my vim is compiled with python, but not python3.